# Android Studio 2.0 stable , slow down app startup

Tags: android, android-studio

I was using Android studio 1.5  that was working fine(Not so fast) . today i updated it to 2.0 stable release, and now the startup takes 2-3 minutes to start at first time.Right after first start i check the app info screen i saw that 41MB(varies on diffenrent devices) cache is there on the first start. i don't know whats happening. Here's my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    packagingOptions {


        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'

        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'

        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'

        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'

        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }



    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.app"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false;
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }


}


dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile project(':volley')
    compile project(':android-country-picker-master')
    compile project(':viewPagerIndicator')


    compile ('com.android.support:design:23.1.1') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile ('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile ('com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile ('pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.10'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile ('javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile ('com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile ('com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6'
    compile ('com.google.guava:guava:18.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile ('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

}
```

any help would be appreciated, Thank you

Comment: dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

Comment: change heap size it will help you...

Comment: Start up takes time due to various indexing done by Android Studio but if you have instant run enabled next build will not take that much time. All this size increase is probably I think of this issue

Comment: @RickyPatel, it was 4g before, but 4g does not work on low end devices

Comment: @VivekMishra , i am not talking about the build  makin, i am talking about the when a build install on device , and first time i tried to opne a app it is taking 2-3 minutes to open, stays on blank screen

Comment: @warlock try to remove catch file of studio then check this problem is occur when more libs is adding in project.

Comment: Same here, Observer @first startup, size gradually increased , the app caches all resources. Just tried an app having no resources, didn't happen there.

Comment: Observed ":transformClassesWithInstantRunSlicerForDebug" and ":transformClasses_enhancedWithInstant+reloadDexForDebug". Executed with older grade command set and worked fine.

Comment: since date i updated android studio 2.1.1, app start slower on device, it stays blank screen about 2.5s. Before my app started within 0.5s to see UI. Should i downgrade android studio?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run

> When using Instant Run with a project configured for Legacy Multidex—that is, when build.gradle is configured withmultiDexEnabled true and **minSdkVersion 20** or lower—build performance may decrease when deploying a **clean build to target devices running Android 5.0** (API level 21) or higher.
>
> [..] To improve clean build performance during development, consider
> creating a product flavor withminSdkVersion 21.

Try implementing this in your gradle

```
android {
productFlavors {
    // Define separate dev and prod product flavors.
    dev {
        // dev utilizes minSDKVersion = 21 to allow the Android gradle plugin
        // to pre-dex each module and produce an APK that can be tested on
        // Android Lollipop without time consuming dex merging processes.
        minSdkVersion 21
    }
    prod {
        // The actual minSdkVersion for the application.
        minSdkVersion 14
    }
}
      ...
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                                             'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

}
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments above, Gradle commands for the feature  "Instant run" causes this problem.
I reverted (forced) to fallback to 2.8 and I am not facing this problem anymore.

**Update**
Only the Debug compile has this problem as It needs hot swipe, No problems with the release

Answer (score 1):

This is normal, and is part of the `Instant Run` feature. In theory, subsequent loads should be faster. My first few loads took over 5 minutes ! But now seem faster than my previous 1.5 minutes:

> Introduced in Android Studio 2.0, Instant Run is a behavior for the
> Run  and Debug  commands that significantly reduces the time between
> updates to your app. **Although your first build may take longer to**
> **complete**, Instant Run pushes subsequent updates to your app without
> building a new APK, so changes are visible much more quickly.
>
> Instant Run is supported only when you deploy the debug build variant,
> use Android Plugin for Gradle version 2.0.0 or higher, and set
> minSdkVersion to 15 or higher in your app's module-level build.gradle
> file. For the best performance, set minSdkVersion to 21 or higher.
>
> After deploying an app, a small, yellow thunderbolt icon appears
> within the Run  button (or Debug   button), indicating that Instant
> Run is ready to push updates the next time you click the button.
> Instead of building a new APK, it pushes just those new changes and,
> in some cases, the app doesn't even need to restart but immediately
> shows the effect of those code changes.
>
> Instant Run pushes updated code and resources to your connected device
> or emulator by performing a hot swap, warm swap, or cold swap. It
> automatically determines the type of swap to perform based on the type
> of change you made. The following table describes how Instant Run
> behaves when you push certain code changes to a target device.

Source: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-studio.html?utm_campaign=android_launch_studio_040716&utm_source=anddev&utm_medium=blog#instant-run

Note:  (Make sure you upgrade gradle when prompted, after installing android studio 2.0)

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in Android Studio 2.3. Beta 1 is currently available, and I'd encourage you to give it a try.

Release announcement: http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio23beta1isnowavailable
Download links: http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest/

Answer (score -1):

As already mentioned by Ricky Patel:

```
dexOptions { preDexLibraries = false javaMaxHeapSize "4g" }
```

does indeed work, not sure why by it completely removed the startup delay for me.